# Im facing this error Failed to resolve: com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, parse-platform

Im trying to implement Parse in my android studio project.
I have followed this guide https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/parse-android-sdk
until step 4 :
`implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.0.0"`

Since this, i have this error message when i try to sync

Failed to resolve: com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.0.0"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH79N.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested it here, and I was able to make it work.

See my entire file, maybe you can use it as a reference. I got it from here: https://github.com/templates-back4app/push-android-latest-version/blob/master/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.application"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.0-alpha04'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha07'

    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.7"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

Comment: thank a lot for response.

I have tried your but always the same error message.

could it be linked to my version of java/android studio ?

Comment: I just export your project https://github.com/templates-back4app/push-android-latest-version/blob/master/app/build.gradle and build work. So it seems to be a problem with my project. I will merge to continue my learning. Thx a lot